# RemainAfterExit in Upstart

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-14.04, rhel6, upstart

Is there an Upstart equivalent to systemd's RemainAfterExit?

I have an upstart task that exec's a script that completes quickly when the task is started. However, I would still like that task to report as active so that I can subsequently 'stop' the task and have it execute a cleanup script.

In systemd, I would do the following:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_script.sh create %i
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/my_script.sh delete %i
```

How would I do the same thing in Upstart?

Answer (score 1):

You could either add one `read` statement at the end of your script to pause execution or you could use `pre-start exec` instead of `exec` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/488055/459661) (although I can't confirm the effectiveness of this solution).